# Why is the "this" pointer used to call derived member functions?

Tags: c++, this

While reading a tutorial about virtual functions(not relavant for this example) on [this](https://www.programiz.com/cpp-programming/virtual-functions) link, I found this code.

```
class Weapon
{
    public:
      void features()
         { cout << "Loading weapon features.\n"; }
};



class Bomb : public Weapon
{
    public:
       void features()
         { 
            this->Weapon::features(); 
            cout << "Loading bomb features.\n"; 
         }
};
```

The class Weapon is derived by the class Bomb, where the member function of Weapon is called.

Why is the function Weapon::features() called with the "this" pointer? Isn't this already implicit given?

Comment: It's a matter of personal style. Some programmers use `this->` to access members, some do not.

Comment: `this->` is needed in a rare case when both base and derived are templates and base template parameters depend on derived template parameters. But here it's useless.

Comment: one could argue that `Weapon::features()` looks too similar too a call of a static method, which would be a good reason to prepend `this->`, however, its just a matter of style

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Base does not have to be a template, but has to depend on (or be) a template parameter of Derived.

Comment: You can sorta tell that it took him at least 15 minutes of his life to figure this out.  An extension keyword like `__super` is pretty nice, but unlikely to be adopted :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `this` is implicitly given, and it is often a matter of style whether to write it explicitly or not. In your case I'd say that it does not improve readability.

In other cases, however, it makes sense or is even necessary to explicitly write `this` in order to avoid naming conflicts between local variables and data members. Consider, for example, the following program:

```
class SomeClass {
public:
    void print(int amount) const {
        cout << amount << endl;
    }
    int amount = 10;
};

int main() {
    SomeClass c;
    c.print(20);
}
```

The output is `20`, an if one wanted to access the data member, one would have to write `cout << this->amount << endl`. Yes, bad style, maybe. But in a technical sense an explicit `this` sometimes is even required.

Comment: btw. That parameter / field name collision is why some standards recommend adding underscore at end of field name - https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html#Variable_Names

Comment: Is there a case where the `this` pointer is needed to call a member function?

Comment: No; a member function call always hides any "global" function with the same name/parameter set. So `this` for member functions is technically superfluous.